# Apply form_for data to a fillable pdf form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rubygems

I'm new to rails and gems, and I was wondering if there is a particular gem or service that I can use to take form_for data to populate the empty fields of a fillable pdf. Any suggestions all mighty SO_gods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using your form data to generate an html page (like you would normally in rails) and then converting that web page to a pdf.  We use acts_as_flying_saucer for html->pdf conversion, it's a rails wrapper for flying_saucer which is a java app.

https://github.com/dagi3d/acts_as_flying_saucer

We make a lot of pdfs on our site, and doing them as web pages first is a very friendly and easy approach.

EDIT

I just re-read your question and saw the fillable part:  you may not be able to do this with flying_saucer, sorry.

Have a look at prawn and prawn-forms: the prawn-forms extension looks like it will do what you need (i've not used prawn myself but it's quite popular).

http://prawnpdf.org/

https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails

https://github.com/yob/prawn-forms